# Non-specific Heroku deployment error (Node.js, socket.io)

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

My intention is to deploy a simple web app on Heroku.
I used to locally host this app, but now I am using Heroku to get it online.

When opening the app, it simply says: "An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served."

There is no error number or no hint to why the app doesn't work, here is all relevant code:

**Client-side code:**

```
var socket;
socket = io.connect("https://fakename.herokuapp.com");
```

**server-side node.js code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var Victor = require('victor');

var app = express();

var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, listen);

function listen() {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("server is up");
}

app.use(express.static('public'));

var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Procfile and package.json included of course.

Comment: Type "heroku logs" that it will log out error message raised in your heroku app instance.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention this, but there were no errors in the build log whatsoever, the only thing even close to an error was NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing the wrong instance when you new up a socket.io instance. Please try this

```
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = socket(http);

...

io.on("connection", socket=> ()=>{...});
http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

It's from the official doc https://socket.io/docs/ and I am using for my current projects.
Also, actually I haven't tried running web socket service in heroku instance. However, heroku basically provides auto-scaling service to the customers. That means your app can run on a multiple number of servers through some load balancing. This could cause websocket fail to work properly. In this case what usually is encouraged to do is to implement sticky sessions. Please try the codes I posted above, and please let me know if it also doesn't work.